# Docusign API - External app connecting to others instances

Tags: docusignapi

I am build an app that need to plug to Docusign APIs and pull a user list.
My app is using a Docusign sandbox for tests.

the questions I have are:

- Is it possible for companies to give consent to my app **without Admin consent** (those companies won't have my Integrator key)?
- If not, can I ask then to **create an app into their Docusign portal** to be able to use their ClientId/Secret to access their data?
- Am I **forced to have an Organization-enabled Docusign sandbox** to use the admin Consent flow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great questions!

**Is it possible for companies to give consent to my app without Admin consent (those companies won't have my Integrator key)?**

Administrative consent or Individual consent by the end customer?

As you've noted, Administrative consent (via the Organization Administration system) can normally only be given to applications using Integration Keys managed by the account.

Good news, DocuSign has a new API that can be used by ISV applications sold to end users to enable the end user's Organizational Administration to grant Administrative consent for the org's users.

See docs for [Admin consent for external applications](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#admin-consent-for-external-applications) That API is designed to be used during installation/configuration of the ISV's app. It enables the customer to grant administrative consent. Organization Administration is needed by the end customer, but not SSO.

Individual Consent can also be used by your end customers: during installation/configuration of your application, you can provide the url for the first part of the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow to the user(s) who will be impersonated. They, as a one time task, will open that URL to grant consent for your IK to use signature and impersonation scope for them.

**If not, can I ask them to create an app in their Docusign portal to be able to use their ClientId/Secret to access their data?**

The `Secret` is used for Authorization Code Grant. Did you mean the client id's `Private Key`?

Answer: Yes, but there are several steps they'd need to take:

1. Create their own IK in demo
2. Go through the Go Live process. They'd need access to your app to do this.
3. After completing Go Live, they'd need to manage the IK in their account.

**Am I forced to have an Organization-enabled Docusign sandbox to use the admin Consent flow?**

Yes. They are available without charge, contact DocuSign tech support to turn on the feature in your DocuSign sandbox (demo) account. Note that you do not need SSO for testing administrative granting of consent.

Comment: Thanks Larry for your thorough answer, that really helps!